# How to detect if an entity is outdated and needs to be reloaded

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-5

Let's say I do a query against my context to retrieve a particular entity.

Now I'd like to find the best way to know if the corresponding row in the database (let's stay simple with a 1-1 mapping between entity and SQL Table) has changed since the creation of my entity.

I've thought about using a TimeStamp column and execute a simple query each each I want to know if the entity is outdated, like:

```
var uptodate = (from e in context.mySet
                where e.TimeStamp == entityTimeStamp
                select e).Any();
```

By indexing the TimeStamp column, I think it would be a fast way to go, but unfortunately I didn't find any confirmation around the internet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further tests and investigation using the TimeStamp and a query to know if it's still the same (more precisely if the given value is still in the table) seems the best way to go.

Such mechanism needs an index on the TimeStamp column to ensure the best performance (roughly O(Log(n) instead of (O(n)).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to do this without having to modify your table, you could use the `CHECKSUM` command and add an additional column to your mapping (as a view presumably). This way you don't have to worry about adding a new column to the database.

Something like this should work :

```
select *, 
    BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) as CheckSumValue
from test WITH (NOLOCK);
```

Here is some sample [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16179/2).

With that said, sometimes it's preferable to have a ModifiedDate field in your table.  If that is the case, then that would surely be your best way of checking for changes.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I look for the best way to do this in C#, on the client side.

Comment: I wasn't implying running that server side on a different prop, but rather adding it to a view and using your ORM to handle that column.  Works the same way as adding an additional column, without having to add a new column and worry about updating it when the entity changes.  You would use similar code to that of yours above to see if anything in the table has changed.  Perhaps I misunderstood your question.  Good luck.

Comment: Indeed, but I don't mind adding and extra column, I think the TimeStamp should be faster than a checksum computing. Speed is the most important for me right now.

Comment: I would definitely agree.  Querying an existing field in a table would be quicker than any computations.  Just have used this in the past pretty successfully and thought it was an interesting approach to your question.  Sounds like you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If optimistic locking is OK, How about adding the  [ConcurrencyCheck]  attribute to the field in your data class. This causes the update to fail if the record has been modified.

The attribute is from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations